# Xamarin for Salesforce using DeveloperForce packages

Tags: xamarin, salesforce

Hoping someone else is using DeveloperForce with Xamarin to access Salesforce -- or have other options for accessing Salesforce from Xamarin solutions.

After updating the appropriate credentials, debugging with the supplied DeveloperForce SimpleConsole sample (Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) is successful in authorizing with the Salesforce sandbox and retrieving a list of accounts.

I then created a Xamarin solution (PCL/iOS/Droid) using the same code as from the SimpleConsole sample.  When I debug, it hangs on the attempt to authorize.  The `UsernamePasswordAsync()` call to obtain the client just hangs -- doesn't fail, doesn't return, nothing.

Are there other steps to take when using the DeveloperForce SDK methods from a PCL and/or mobile solution?  Below, I've included links to the samples and another page from SalesforceStack.

URL to DevloperForce samples
https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET

URL to SalesforceStack post
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/xamarin-sdk-key-not-found-exception/53168

Comment: I've confirmed that the task that invokes UsernamePasswordAsync() is simply not returning.  I can debug through the code and see the method complete but the Task.Wait() method is never satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOH! It was blocking on the main thread.  Refactoring the code around and invoking it from a button (Command), the task is now returning.